# vba are empty values treated as zeroes in equality comparison

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to skip records which either have a zero as the value or is empty. As of now, i have the following code that checks for both explicitly, but I feel that the second check is redundant. But I want to confirm that I am right so that I can remove the second part of the IF

```
IF (CellInValue(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt) = 0 Or CellInValue(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt) = "") Then
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `""` is not equal to `0` and will produce a type mismatch in a strongly typed scenario, or won't come out as equal if used as `Variant`.

When the cell is empty, it's also not the same as zero, but it will come out as same, because in VB, `Empty = 0` gives `True` because of implicit conversion happening in the background.
Same for `Empty = ""`, will also give `True` for the same reason.

So you need both checks.

Comment: thanks. Can you explain what you mean by strongly typed scenario - can you give some code where the first and second part will give different results.

Comment: If `CellInValue(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt)` = 0 then the first condition will be true, and the second will be false. If you try `0 = ""` you will get a type mismatch error. If your function returns a long or integer or any numeric type, checking its result against "" would cause the mismatch error.

Answer (score 4):

GSerg is completely correct.

If you really wanted to avoid doing 2 different checks, you could change your If to something like this:

```
If Clng(0 & CellInValue(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt)) = 0 then
```

This returns true when `CellInValue(RowInCrnt, ColInCrnt)` is "", Empty, or 0.

Though if your function could return letters instead of numbers, this will have a type mismatch error in that case.