# How can I compare "" with double (issue to converting VB 6.0 to VB.NET )

Tags: vb.net, vb6

In VB 6.0, Somebody made Program.
And In that Program, He used

```
If tmpVar <> "" Then
```

Yeah It worked very well in 6.0.
`If tmpVar has string`, it works.
`If tmpVar has double`, it works too.

I think In vb 6.0, `""` means just something like null.
So whatever tmpVar has anyValue, It just works. But When I converted this Program to .Net.
It doesn't work anymore

Because In .Net, "" can't compare with double. I think In .Net `""` is just string not like null like vb 6.0

So I used `Nothing` instead of `""`. But it has problem too.

For example When I use this

```
If tmpVar <> Nothing Then
```

It looks like no problem.
But, If `tmpVar` has number `0`, it doesn't work because they think `Nothing` and `0` is same.
I didn't wish that. cuz 0 and nothing is different. but they think they're same.

So I changed my program again

```
If tmpVar IsNot Nothing Then
```

Yeah. It looks like no problem again. but If `tmpVar` has "", it doesn't work.

So In conclusion, In vb 6.0, this `""` means empty like null. and it can compare with anytype.

But After converting, In vb.net this `""` doesn't mean empty like null. it is just string. it can't compare with doubletype. and even though I changed `""` to `Nothing`, it is not same with vb 6.0 `""`. And I gave you example above. So If there is anybody who know about this solution, please let me know. It makes me crazy.

Comment: What type is `tmpVar` declared as in your code? My guess is `tmpVar` was a `Variant` in VB6, right?

Comment: It might help if you showed us where `tmpVar` is declared and how a value is assigned to it. Perhaps the [Double.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) would be useful.

Comment: I think Dim tmpVar As object

Comment: Is tempVar a String or a Double? Are you not explicitly declaring it? If it is a string you can use `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmpVar) Then`

Comment: In VB 6.0, somebody made A BAD Program. if tmpVar works with double make it a double and handle the conversion when required.

Answer (score 5):

No, `""` is just a string, not "null", but there is [implicit conversion happening in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13173575/11683) that may make you believe it is "null".

I asssume `tmpVar` is Variant in VB6 and `Object` in VB.NET.
Then the person who wrote the VB6 program did a bad job, because storing `""` in a meant-to-be-number variable is not the right way of doing it, there are special values `Empty` and `Null` for this purpose.

The idiomatic way of doing this in .NET is using the nullable type:

```
Dim tmpVar as Double?
if tmpVar Is Nothing Then
   ...
End If
```

Comment: Don't you need to also check `If tmpVar.HasValue`, as you're using a nullable type?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Checking a nullable variable for `Is Nothing` is same as calling `HasValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `tmpVar` is an `Object`, then you need to use `TryParse` for the types you want to compare against, like this:

```
Dim number As Double

If Double.TryParse(tmpVar.ToString(), number) Then
    ' Use number here, because tmpVar could successfully be cast to a Double type
Else
    ' tmpVar could not successfully be cast to a Double type, so raise exception or message to user
End If
```